# Nested dictionary - Class?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently working on a Python config parser, in this case, I need to build a nested dictionary. First, I tried the usual "function", but now, I'm looking for a class with methods.

My idea :

```
Class Dict
-var dict_test => {}
- method level_up(key, value={})
- method level_down(key, value={})
- method current_add(key, value={})

d = Dict()
print(d.dict_test) => {}

d.level_up("Test1","Value1")
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1"}}

d.current_add("Test2")
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1", "Test2": {}}}

d.level_up("Test3")
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1", "Test2": {"Test3", {}}}}}

d.level_up("Test4","Value4")
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1", "Test2": {"Test3", {"Test4","Value4"}}}}}

d.level_down("Test5","Value5") 
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1", "Test2": {"Test3", {"Test4","Value4"} "Test5": "Value5"}}}

d.level_down("Test6","Value6") 
print(d.dict_test) => {{"Test1": "Value1", "Test2": {"Test3", {"Test4","Value4"} "Test5": "Value5"}, "Test6": "Value6"}}
```

Question : Does this kind of Class exist? 
I tried to develop this need, but my skills are not enough.

Comment: No, this class does not exist. You have no choice but to implement it yourself. We won't write the whole thing for you, so please post your code so we can help you fix it.